# Filtering twice in crossfilter.js giving unconsistent results

Tags: crossfilter

I am processing data from a school survey. The data has sex, grade and answer attributes. Ultimately, I want to be able to show a grouped bar chart where viewers can see answers from boys and girls. To get the data I am filtering with crossfilter.js, using first a filter for boys and then a filter for girls. I might be doing things very wrong as I get unconsistent results. Probably I am missing some points about crossfilter.js's philosophy. I would like to know if my implementation is correct, or if I should use crossfilter in a different way.

Note that the question is encoded by its index (B-13)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Prueba con crossfilter</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "../static/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src  = "../static/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var data =[{"grado": 6, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 1},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 5},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 5},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 5},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 2},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 2},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 2},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 1},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 1},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 4},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 4},
    {"grado": 6, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 3},
    {"grado": 7, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 2},
    {"grado": 7, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 1},
    {"grado": 7, "Sexo": 2, "B-13": 2},
    {"grado": 7, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 1},
    {"grado": 7, "Sexo": 1, "B-13": 5}];


    // Crossfilter:
    cf = crossfilter(data);
    bySex = cf.dimension(function (d) { return d["Sexo"]; });
    byB13 = cf.dimension(function (d) { return d["B-13"]; });

    // Men
    bySex.filter("1"); 
    totalMen = cf.groupAll().value();
    console.log("Total men " + totalMen);

    menAnswers = byB13.group().top(Infinity);
    console.log(menAnswers);

    //Women
    bySex.filterAll();
    bySex.filter("2");
    totalWomen = cf.groupAll().value();
    console.log("Total women " + totalWomen);

    womenAnswers = byB13.group().top(Infinity);
    console.log(womenAnswers);


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to build your groups twice. Crossfilter is stateful, so just build your groups, apply the filters you want, and then query your groups. Then apply different filters and query your groups again. That said, it seems what you are doing should work. What are you seeing that is inconsistent? Might be good to create a jsFiddle demonstration.

Comment: @EthanJewett, thank you. I found inconsistent that answers for men and women turned out to be the same. I created the jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uxmjrasq/13/) to show it, but it happens to work when data is mapped to onscreen html elements. However, when answers are printed to console (which I was relying on for debugging), answers are still the same. Do you happen to know why this is so?

Comment: It's because the values are updated after writing to the console, and the console shows you the *current* version, not the version at the time you write to the console. Use `console.log( JSON.stringify(answers.top(Infinity)) )` if you want to see the version of the object at the time you write to the console and you will see that they are different.